# better understanding of getline() and cin

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

Trying to get some basic understanding of console functionalities. I am having issues so consider the following...

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>

using namespace std;

/*
This is a template Project
*/

void MultiplicationTable(int x);

int main()
{

    int value = 0;

    printf("Please enter any number \n\n");
    getline(cin, value);

    MultiplicationTable(value);


    getchar();


    return 0;
}
```

I actually based this off code from http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/basic_io/ . My IDE is not recognizing getline() so of course when I compile the application. I get an error

```
'getline': identifier not found
```

Now take a look at this code

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>

using namespace std;

/*
This is a template Project
*/

void MultiplicationTable(int x);

int main()
{

    int value = 0;

    printf("Please enter any number \n\n");
    cin>>value;

    MultiplicationTable(value);


    getchar();


    return 0;
}
```

When I execute this line of code the console window opens and immediately closes. I think I a missing something about cin. I do know that it delimits spaces but I don't know what else. what should I use for input to make my life easier.

Comment: Well, I think the reason that the first code doesn't work is because getline expects (char* s, streamsize n ), and cin is an istream object, so that's why the compiler complained.

I'm not sure why the window doesn't stay open for the second code.

Comment: Add brackets at the end of void MultiplicationTable(int x) like so void MultiplicationTable(int x){};

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function `getline()` is declared in the string header. So, you have to add `#include <string>`.
It is defined as `istream& getline ( istream& is, string& str );`, but you call it with an `int` instead of a string object.

About your second question:

> When I execute this line of code the console window opens and immediately closes

There is probably still a `'\n'` character from your input in the stream, when your program reaches the function `getchar()` (which I assume you put there so your window doesn't close).  You have to flush your stream. An easy fix is, instead of `getchar()`, add the line

```
 int c;
 while((c = getchar()) != '\n'){}
```

This will flush your stream until the next line-break.

Remark: `conio.h` is not part of the c++ standard and obsolete.

Comment: thanks. I am really confused with this iostream. I have ran into previous problems where characters were still in the iostream and therefore the application did not function correctly. Is there any resources or anything you can say about how to address those types of issues ??

Answer (score 3):

The getline function reads strings, not integers:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string line;
    getline( cin, line );
    cout << "You entered: " << line << endl;
}
```

Comment: @numerical You will have to rephrase that.

Comment: The second code I have uses the cin functionality. If you run that code in your compiler. It executes and then ends immediately. It doesnt leave me the time to input anything or do anything at that.

Comment: @numerical I think you are asking a question regarding your IDE - which one are you using? In other words, how are you compiling and running this code?

Answer (score 0):

You are `exiting the program` before you can view the results because (I'm guessing) you `double-clicked` the `.exe file` from inside a Windows Explorer (or the Desktop) view in order to execute.  Instead, go to Start, Run, type in cmd.exe and open a command window.  Navigate to where your program resides.  Type in your program's name on the command line and execute.  It will stay open until you `intentionally` close the command window.