# how to use getline correctly

Tags: c++, getline

I wrote a program that uses `getline()` function, but I don't know how should I use `getline()` in the correct way. I've searched it on the Internet but I just found something about about using `getchar()` with `getline()` or `cin.ignore()`. I tried and none of them worked and I don't know what is the problem and why `getline()` function needs `getchar()` or `cin.ignore()` to work correctly?

My Input

```
2   
Alderaan   
1000.00 2000.00 3000.00   
Dantooine   
-1000.00 1000.00 1000.00   
Circarpous Major   
-500.00 500.00 -500.00   
Y’Toub   
-500.00 -500.00 500.00
```

here is my code:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    long long int  x, y, z, x1, y1, z1;
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    string s, p;
    while (n--)
    {
        getline(cin, s);
        cin >> x;
        cin >> y;
        cin >> z; 
        cin.ignore();
        getline(cin, p);
        cin >> x1;
        cin >> y1;
        cin >> z1;
        cin.ignore();
        printf("%s to %s: %.2f\n", s.c_str(), p.c_str(), sqrt(pow(x - x1, 2) + pow(y - y1, 2) + pow(z - z1, 2)));
    }
}
```

Comment: When you say `std::getline()` doesn't work correctly, what exactly do you mean? I'm pretty sure `std::getline()` _does_ work correctly! Note, however, that you _always_ need to check that your input operations were successful. Also, the question you have (I suspect I know what your problem is) actually _was_ answer _numerous_ times! (hint: you are mixing formatted and unformatted input)

Comment: Of Course It's work correctly but I do't know how to use it and Is this function need some other function like getchar() to work???

Comment: Well, one thing to learn about finding solutions is to accurately formulate what the problem is! You stated it doesn't work but didn't state what are the effects and what you expected. Stating the input doesn't really describe what's not working either.

Comment: @Dietmar Kühl I am sorry I edited my question

Comment: so far, there is still not description. There is some irrelevant mention of what you tried to do to resolve the problem ("I search it on net..."), a bit of code and some input. You didn't state _what_ the program is meant to do nor _how_ it fails. Yes, I do know how and why it fails (When reading the above input the second string is empty and the values stopped changing) but this doesn't enable you to resolve your next problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [better understanding of getline() and cin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2915049/better-understanding-of-getline-and-cin)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code mixes formatted input (i.e. using the `>>` operator for input) with unformatted input (in this case using `std::getline()`). Unformatted input does *not* skip leading whitespace while formatted input does skip leading whitespace. In both cases reading stops as soon as the input is the next character wouldn't fit the format.

For example, reading a `double` when the input is `3000.00\n...` stops after reading the last `0` because the '`\n` doesn't fit the `double`s format. The next character in the stream is, thus, a `\n`. The function `std::getline()` reads until it finds the first `\n` which is immediately: it extracts that one character and [successfully] produces an empty line. With your input the sequence `Dantooine` is next but doesn't fit the format of a `double` and the stream goes into fail state.

The simple fix is to always skip leading white space when switching from formatted input to unformatted input, e.g., using the `std::ws` manipulator:

```
std::getline(std::cin >> std::ws, s);
```

Whether this is suitable depends a bit on what you are trying to read. If the strings you want to read can start with a whitespace, you would need to be a bit more careful and, e.g., only extract whitespace up to the next newline:

```
std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

(just ignoring one character may not work, e.g., if the input of the line ends in `3000.00    \n`).

Reading `3000.00` as `long` actually stops at the `.`, i.e., the first change to your program is to correct the type of values read to be `double` rather than `long`. Note that you should also *always* check that your input was successful before processing it. That is, I would actually use something like this:

```
double      x0, y0, z0, x1, y1, z1;
std::string l0, l1;
while (0 < n--
       && std::getline(std::cin >> std::ws, l0)
       && std::cin >> x0 >> y0 >> z0
       && std::getline(std::cin >> std::ws, l1)
       && std::cin >> x1 >> y1 >> z1) {
    // do something with the input
}
```

Comment: Your answer was great but when I putted it in my code I still could't get my truly result why????

Comment: @Danial: I didn't see that you are reading `long` rather than `double`. Since you didn't describe the problem ("it reads the first `s` and `x` OK but everything else is wrong") I didn't spot that: change the type of `x`, `y`, and `z` to be `double`. Due to the missing problem description all answers (except the one from Kerrek SB) assumed you are looking at a different problem than the one you actually encountered so far!

Comment: The input file will begin with a line containing the integer n (0 < n < 200), representing the number of entries to process   names may contain alpha-numeric characters, whitespace, and punctuation names will be no larger than 30 characters the x, y, and z coordinates will be real numbers listed with two digits of precision to the right of the decimal point, with -100,000.00 < x, y, z < 100,000.00,

Answer (score 2):

`cin >> z` does not consume the `\n` character. Thus you need a `cin.ignore()` to consume the newline character and make the next `getline()` reading the line you want. The same issue also happens on `cin >> z1`.

Comment: @dornhege: the teacher is a bit "evil": if you look at the input closely, e.g., by editing the answer and going with the cursor to the end of the line you'll see that there are trailing spaces before the newline! This is actually good because the teacher forces the students to use a proper approach to skipping whitespace!

Answer (score 0):

It's best not to mix token and line extraction. Just use string streams if you want to tokenize a line. I'd try this:

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

std::string n_str;   // for the first number, parse it later

if (!std::getline(std::cin, n_str))
{
    // error, die
}

for (std::string name, numbers;
     std::getline(std::cin, name) && std::getline(std::cin, numbers); )
{
    std::istringstream iss(numbers);
    double x, y, z;
    if (!(iss >> x >> y >> z >> std::ws) || iss.get() != EOF)
    {
        // parse error, die
    }

    // "name", "x", "y", "z" are usable now
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try it

```
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    long long int  x, y, z, x1, y1, z1;
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    string s, p;
    while (n--)
    {
        cin.ignore();
        cin.clear();
        getline(cin, s);
        cin >> x;
        cin >> y;
        cin >> z;
        cin.ignore();
        cin.clear();
        getline(cin, p);
        cin >> x1;
        cin >> y1;
        cin >> z1;
        printf("%s to %s: %.2f\n", s.c_str(), p.c_str(), sqrt(pow(x - x1, 2) + pow(y - y1, 2) + pow(z - z1, 2)));
    }
}
```

you have twice in the first time you enter the string.

Comment: Note that this code also doesn't work because the input posted actually contains multiple spaces between the last digit and the newline! You need to skip all of them.